# Exception while calling savechange method while adding, removing or modifying entity. IMP

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I am working on Entity Framework 4.1 . Here Adding control into database using AddObject() and save that suing SaveChange() methods.

But Once I delete that added control and try to add again same I am getting this error again and again (Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.) but not able to add it. Once i close my application then try to add then I am able to add that control.

I tried to search a lot here and there how it going wrong but could not find solution. As I am new born in field in Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

As in this scenario i was calling SaveChange() method of Entity framework object context after every operation like add, delete and modification. But i was getting exception back to back.It got solved by 
By calling method like this
public void Save(object entity)
        {
            using (var transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction())
            {

```
            try
            {
                SaveChanges();
                transaction.Commit();
             }
             catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException)
             {
                 if (ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entity).State == EntityState.Deleted || ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entity).State == EntityState.Modified)
                        this.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, entity);
                  else if (ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entity).State == EntityState.Added)
                        Detach(entity);
                  AcceptAllChanges(); 
                  transaction.Commit();
              }

        }
    }
```